# Batch file concatenate command line argument

Tags: batch-file

As an example, I created a batch file named `concatenate.bat`:

```
@echo off
set foo=%1\bar
echo %foo%
```

When I run `concatenate.bat "C:\somewhere\with spaces"`

I want foo to output:
`"C:\somewhere\with spaces\bar"`

But instead I get:
`"C:\somewhere\with spaces"\bar`

---

I also tried: `set "foo=%1\bar"`

Which outputs: `"C:\somewhere\with spaces"\bar`

---

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@echo off
set foo="%~1\bar"
echo %foo%
```

Comment: Will someone explain what is going on in this answer, please?

Comment: Explanation on what %~1 does can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426129/difference-between-1-and-1-in-batch). In short it  expands %1 removing any surrounding quotes.